# Post And Redirect in WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

I'm trying to implement the payment gateway. in the last step i have to post the data to the specific URL then redirect the client. in asp.net its so simple. i just wrote a java script in order to do that. then i call it like this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "ClientScript", "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'> postRefId('" + "13" + "');</script> ", false);
```

but now i want to do the same in wcf service. i have no idea how can i do it. i found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37539/Redirect-and-POST-in-ASP-NET) article but it doesn't work.
i also try this but it didn't work nether:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = body.Length;
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    writer.Write(body);

HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i find the answer.
it appear we cant redirect and post in wcf service. so i added a aspx page to my project. then i redirect to this page like this:

```
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Redirect;
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Location = "mypage.aspx?123456";
```

then i use this class:

```
public class RemotePost
{
    private string url;
    private string method;
    private Dictionary<string, string> inputs;

    public string Url
    {
        set { url = value; }
        get { return url; }
    }
    public string Method
    {
        set { method = value; }
        get { return method; }
    }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Inputs
    {
        set { inputs = value; }
        get { return inputs; }
    }


    public RemotePost(string url, string method = "post")
    {
        Url = url;
        Method = method;
        Inputs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    public void PostAndRedirect()
    {
        var postString = new StringBuilder();
        postString.Append("<html><head>");
        postString.Append("</head><body onload=\"document.form1.submit();\">");
        postString.Append("<form name=\"form1\" method=\"" + Method + "\" action=\"" + Url + "\" >");

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> oPar in Inputs)
            postString.Append(string.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{1}\">", oPar.Key, oPar.Value));

        postString.Append("</form>");
        postString.Append("</body></html>");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(postString.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
    public void Add(string name, string value)
    {
        lock (Inputs)
            Inputs.Add(name, value);
    }
}
```

in my page load event in order to redirect and post. this way i can redirect and post in wcf service.
hope could help.